# How to represent a point in 2d space in minizinc?

Tags: arrays, optimization, minizinc

Lets say I have 2 points in space. Let's say p1=(1.2,2.3) and p2(1.2,3) and more generally an array of N nodes with points in space. How to put that to minizinc terms?

Comment: How about using a 2-dimensional array of floats? For an example see https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/modelling2.html, especially the array `array[HEIGHT,WIDTH] of var float: t;`

Comment: Example given (
array[HEIGHT,WIDTH] of var float: t; % temperature at point (i,j))  is a 2d array, I am looking for 1d array of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Seems it is easier than I thought:

```
int: n;
set of int: NUM = 1..n;
array[NUM] of var NUM: x;
array[NUM] of var NUM: y;
```